# Discord Bot commands not found

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a Discord bot, here is my code.
I don't know if the @commands.command() is right.
I tried to fix it but i couldn't do it.
And you can see the commands are right there so I don't know what is wrong whit this

**main.py**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


#import all of the cogs
from music_cog import music_cog

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = discord.Intents.all())

#remove the default help command so that we can write out own
bot.remove_command('help')

async def setup(bot): 
        await bot.add_cog(music_cog(bot))
#start the bot with our token
bot.run("TOKEN")
```

**music_cog.py**

```
from ast import alias
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self,ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
           await ctx.send("Flaco, no estas en ningun canal de voz. Despertate perro")
        voice_channel =  ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.voice_channel.move_to(voice_channel)

    @commands.command()
    async def disconnect(self,ctx):
        ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
            

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, url):
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delax_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio'}
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download = False)
            url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
            source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2,
            **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
            vc.play(source)
    
    @commands.command()
    async def pause(self,ctx):
        ctx.voice_client.pause()
        await ctx.send("Dale master ahi te freno la musiquita ")

    @commands.command()
    async def resume(self,ctx):
        ctx.voice_client.resume()
        await ctx.send("Suena como un Duna planchado al piso OAAA")

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(music(client))
```

And I get this error:

`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "join" is not found`

I don't know how to solve it

Answer (score -1):

when I run this code, it works completely fine, your imports are not at the top so I have no idea if you left those out or if you don't have them in your actual code, make sure you have your imports

the code works fine with the correct imports at the top

Comment: I do have them, i just didn't post it sorry, i still don't know why it does not work

Comment: hm, I don't know then, because it works perfectly on my computer